# Why is buying starting items so expensive?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, equipment, pricing, wealth

According to the PHB (p. 15), you can choose your own starting items instead of taking those listed under class and background:

> Instead of taking the gear given to you by your class and background,
>   you can purchase your starting equipment. You have a number of **gold
>   pieces** (gp) to spend based on your class, as shown in chapter 5.
>   Extensive lists of equipment, with prices, also appear in that
>   chapter. If you wish, you can also have one trinket at no cost (see
>   the trinket table at the end of chapter 5).

However, this seems unreasonably expensive in comparison. Have I missed something? If not, why is this so expensive?

For example, a Scholar's Pack is listed as 40 gp (PHB, p. 151). The listed starting coinage to buy the items with is for e.g. a warlock listed as 4d4×10 (PHB, p. 143). This means that with about average luck when rolling for the starting gold, you can just afford a Scholar's Pack and that's it. No weapons, no armor. How come?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your calculation is off. The expected value of 4d4×10 is 100, more than double the cost of the pack.

Even for classes that buy relatively expensive starting items (mainly armor) this budget won't be tight (they get 5d4×10, expected 125, chain mail costs 75). The possibility of rolling low is a risk you accept for the possibility of getting more money.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60553/discussion-on-answer-by-szega-why-is-buying-starting-items-so-expensive).